# How to make a default selected select react attribue a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, ecmascript-6, html-select

I'm trying to make a default selected select react attribue a string. Is it possible with react?

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-forked-vkxnxg?file=/src/components/NewTask.js

```js
//react child component

const Component = () => {
  return (
<select value={"select an option"}>        /// place a string here
  <option>
    Option 1
  </option>
  <option >
    Option 2
  </option>
</select>
}
```

Comment: Either `value="aLiteralString"` or `value={aStringRef}`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sandbox shared, you can have a `disabled` option with some `value` and then set the `defaultValue` of `select` the same value

```js
        <select onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)} defaultValue="select an option" >
          <option value="select an option" disabled>
            Select author
          </option>
          {authors.map((author) => (
            <option key={author.author_name} value={author.author_name}>
              {author.author_name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```